Permission Denied Error When Creating Files in NFS-Mounted Directory
I have an NFS share, configured on HP 3PAR storage 8200 with the following details:
NFS Share Name: Thunder
The NFS share is successfully mounted on my Linux machine at /Thunder:
Mount Command: mount.nfs 192.168.x.x:/VFS_FPG/VFS/VFS/Thunder /Thunder
I also have a RedHat IPA server where I created a group named thunder and added members test, test1, and test2 in this group. I assigned the following permissions to the mounted directory
chown -R root:thunder /Thunder  
chmod -R 775 /Thunder

However, when I switch to the user test and try to create a file or directory under /Thunder, it will get the "permission denied" error.
What I've tried:

Verified that the user test is a member of the thunder group. Checked the ownership and permissions on /Thunder (shows as root:thunder with 775 permissions).


Not doubting you, but can you edit your post to include the output of id test and ls -ld /Thunder?
